# How to decode an object that already has a different decode logic for API?

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

So I have decoded a JSON like so,

```
class MatchDetailResponse: Codable {

static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MatchDetailResponse")

var homeTeam: Team?
var awayTeam: Team?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case homeTeam
    case awayTeam
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(homeTeam, forKey: .homeTeam)
    try container.encode(awayTeam, forKey: .awayTeam)
}

private enum TopLevelKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case teams = "Teams"
    case matchDetail = "Matchdetail"
}

private enum MatchDetailKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case homeTeam = "Team_Home"
    case awayTeam = "Team_Away"
}

private struct DynamicCodingKeys: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    var intValue: Int?
    init?(intValue: Int) {
        return nil
    }
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: TopLevelKeys.self)
    let matchDetailContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: MatchDetailKeys.self, forKey: .matchDetail)
    let homeTeamId = try matchDetailContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: MatchDetailKeys.homeTeam)
    let awayTeamId = try matchDetailContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: MatchDetailKeys.awayTeam)

    let teamContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DynamicCodingKeys.self, forKey: .teams)
    //Assign the home team & away team
    for key in teamContainer.allKeys {
        if key.stringValue == homeTeamId {
            homeTeam = try teamContainer.decode(Team.self, forKey: DynamicCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
        }
        else if key.stringValue == awayTeamId {
            awayTeam = try teamContainer.decode(Team.self, forKey: DynamicCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you see I get a response from an API and I am decoding it and everything works fine. Now my requirement is to store it. So I have encoded it like so. Now the problem is when it will try to decode the stored version, as the decode function is built for the API response, it's not able to decode it.

My requirement is this, how to decode a stored Codable struct, and how exactly we do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the disadvantage of a flattened hierarchy with nested containers. Consider to decode into multiple structs or encode exactly the other way round as the data is being decoded.

Comment: @vadian Is it possible that I try to decode the stored object, if it fails go to the api logic?

Comment: (Almost) everything is possible. But the more conditions you add to the code the more expensive and less efficient it becomes.

Comment: @vadian I'm aware and that's why I was reluctant to use that approach. What could be the best approach for this? Consider a JSON which contains dynamic keys and you are asked to decode it, then encode data for storage, and then decode it back?